# mongoDb find by matching multiple values from same index object array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this documents inside my db, example:

```
{x: 10, y: 20, val: "h"}
{x: 20, y: 70, val: "ho"}
{x: 30, y: 80, val: "hol"}
{x: 40, y: 90, val: "hola"}
{x: 50, y: 29, val: "holas"}
```

i want to get all the documents matching x and y values by passing an array, exampe:

```
[{x: 10, y 20},{x: 20, y 70}]
```

so to return me:

```
[{x: 10, y: 20, val: "h"},{x: 20, y: 70, val: "ho"}]
```

i have tryed in this way but doesn't work:

```
var ricerca = {
   $in: [{x: 10, y 20},{x: 20, y 70}]
};

db.collection('exampe').find(ricerca).toArray(...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `$or`

```
$or: [{x: 10, y: 20},{x: 20, y: 70}]
```